# App crashes when I remove the typeface from a edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I remove bold style from the edittext , while keeping other formats there. My app crashes when I try to set typeface to normal.Setting typeface to bold is not a problem

```
int startSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionStart();
    int endSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionEnd();
    if (startSelection > endSelection) {
        startSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionEnd();
        endSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionStart();
    }
    Spannable s = _etheadertext.getText();
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection, 0);
    _etheadertext.setText(s);
    _etheadertext.setSelection(startSelection, endSelection);

    if(_etheadertext.hasSelection()) {

        try {
            if (_etheadertext.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.NORMAL) {


                _etheadertext.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                chk = false;
            }

            if ((_etheadertext.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) && (chk == true)) {

                _etheadertext.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
               // this line crashes the app

                chk = false;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Logcat please share.

Comment: please show logcat

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Bold` inside `strings.xml` folder.

By code you do it like :

`String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name;`  `mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));`

or :

```
<string name="test">
     <![CDATA[
 <b>bold!</b> normal
    ]]>
</string>
```

and call it like : `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test)));`

Comment: Can you please explain in detail ? I just want to highlight the text and make it bold(the edittext should be bold, not just the highlighted text) and on pressing again make it unbolded , like in Ms Word

Comment: @Sarah check my updated answer for the options to make it Bold.

Comment: So how do we remove the bold from the text and keep the other formatting. Also how can we later check whether the particular string has bold letters in it or not